# Is it possible to consider chlorophyll a as an accessory pigment?

Tags: photosynthesis, definitions

I understand that chlorophyll a is the primary light-capturing pigment. However, in last week's exam, one of the questions asked whether chlorophyll a can function as an accessory pigment.